# Can I claim a ship abandoned if a friend exchanges his ship for a crashed ship?

Tags: no-mans-sky

My friend has an exotic that he doesn’t want. I absolutely love it but I don’t want him to abandon it it for nothing. So I thought well if he exchanges it for a crashed starship, would I be able to claim it once he exchanges it since it would then be considered abandoned? Just to clarify if he found a crashed ship and exchanged his exotic for it would I be able to swoop in and claim it for myself?

Comment: I believe... In the current version you are not able to "Abandon" a ship once you fix and claim a Crashed Starship.  Your only option is to Claim and Add to Collection (or something like that).  The ship that you found the Crashed Starship with is still yours and you may switch ships as you would like.

Comment: @Mumford451 There is a limit to how many ships a person can posess, maybe the person who want's to get the new ship already has the max of ships and wants to trade it in.

Comment: @Wouter After digging around a bit, I cannot find anything specific to the "Beyond" update for NMS regarding how many ships you can possess, so as far as I know, it is still 6.  If I end up finding more info I may turn it into a Question on here and submit the answer.  Good Q though!

Answer (score 2):

I do not believe so. Abandoned ships are not claimable. They are an artifact left over from the previous owner exchanging it for another ship and are no longer really in the game.

Though you can still seem them, you cannot interact with them, so have no way to claim them.

The behavior may have been different in older releases, but at least in the Beyond update, this is the behavior I have experienced.